# EF 4 Code First: How can I modify naming conventions for generated junction tables?

Tags: c#, database-design, asp.net-mvc-3, entity-framework-4, ef-code-first

I'm integrating with an existing database, so I would like the tables generated by my EF4 Code First code to adhere to the table naming conventions which are already in place.

The existing convention is the *singular* entity name, prefixed with a lowercase "t" (e.g `tProduct`), and joined with an underscore for junction tables (e.g `tProduct_tOffer`).

I've achieved this with all the 'standard' tables using the code below. In my `DbContext` I have:

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder) {
    modelBuilder.Conventions.Remove<PluralizingEntitySetNameConvention>();
    modelBuilder.Conventions.Add<TableNamePrefixConvention>();
    base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);
}
```

And the following class adds the "t" to table names:

```
public class TableNamePrefixConvention : IConfigurationConvention<Type, EntityTypeConfiguration> {
    public void Apply(Type typeInfo, Func<EntityTypeConfiguration> configuration) {
        configuration().ToTable("t" + typeInfo.Name);
    }
}
```

However, when a *junction* table is generated, it doesn't adhere to these conventions. So I now have this kind of thing in the list of tables:

```
tOffer
tProduct
ProductOffers
```

In this case, `ProductOffers` should be named `tProduct_tOffer`. How can I force the generated junction table to conform to my naming style?

**Update**: as Ladislav correctly guessed below, I am using CTP5.

Comment: Custom conventions are not part of the final code first release so you are probably using CTP5. It will not work after installing RC or RTW (final) version.

Comment: That's good to know. So what should I be doing?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As I pointed in the comment custom conventions are not available in RC version and will not be available in RTW as well ([official announcement](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/adonet/archive/2011/03/15/ef-4-1-release-candidate-available.aspx)).

You must map it manually:

```
modelBuilder.Entity<Offer>()
    .HasMany(o => o.Products)
    .WithMany(p => p.Offers)
    .Map(m => m.ToTable("tProduct_Offer"));
```

The code snippet is RC version. CTP5 used one more step with `IsIndependent()` but it was removed in RC.